# HTA use existing window

Tags: javascript

This is a stripped down version of code that has always run perfectly but not now in Windows 8/IE10.

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID = "ICP"
INNERBORDER = "no"
CAPTION = "no"
SHOWINTASKBAR = "no"
Scroll = "no"
navigable = "yes"
WINDOWSTATE = "maximize">
<script>
function firstwindow()
{
window.open("red.htm","mywindow");
}
function secondwindow()
{
window.open("blue.htm","mywindow");
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<a onClick = "firstwindow()">OPEN FIRST WINDOW </a>
<a onClick = "secondwindow()">OPEN SECOND WINDOW </a>
</body>
</html>
```

After running and opening the first window (red.htm), I want 'second window' to open in the same window as 'first window'.
It used to work ok but now it opens 'second window' (blue.htm) in a NEW window.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2007/10/08/converting-to-hta.aspx), window.open is not trusted under HTA.

> The window.open command is not considered safe by HTA rules, so any new windows thrown up this way will have (at least in IE7) an address bar. If the content of the window is trusted then you can use window.showModelessDialog to open a window which is considered part of the trusted HTA.

Instead use showModalDialog

Comment: Using 'window.showModelessDialog' instead of 'window.open' still does not address my main concern which is to get 'second window' to open in the same window as 'first window'. I always thought that if the second window had the same name as the first (that's 'mywindow' in the above code) they would open in the same window.

Comment: That seems to be out of the hands of the HTA, hence the showModalDialog can be used instead. Alternatively the opened window can be closed and re-opened

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Operations</title>
    <hta:application id="FileOperationsHTA" 
                     applicationname="FileOperationsHTA" 
                     singleinstance="yes" 
                     maximizebutton="no" 
                     minimizebutton="no" 
                     windowstate="normal" 
                     scroll="no" 
                     navigable="yes" 
                     showintaskbar="no" 
                     contextmenu="no" 
                     selection="no"
    />
</head>


<body onload="showFields()">
    <h1>File Operations</h1>
    <label for="operationCombo">Select operation:</label>
    <select id="operationCombo" onchange="showFields()">
        <option value="">Select an operation</option>
        <option value="move">Move</option>
        <option value="copy">Copy</option>
        <option value="delete">Delete</option>
        <option value="newfolder">New Folder</option>
     <option value="rename">Rename</option>
    </select>

    <div id="sourceField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="sourcePath">Source path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="sourcePath" />
    </div>

    <div id="destinationField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="destinationPath">Destination path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="destinationPath" />
    </div>

    <div id="deleteField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="deletePath">File/Folder to delete:</label>
        <input type="text" id="deletePath" />
    </div>

    <div id="newFolderField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="parentPath">Parent path for new folder:</label>
        <input type="text" id="parentPath" />
        <label for="newFolderName">New folder name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="newFolderName" />
    </div>
 <div id="renameField" style="display: none;">
        <label for="sourcePathRename">Source path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="sourcePathRename" />
        <label for="destinationPathRename">Destination path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="destinationPathRename" />
        <label for="newFileName">New filename:</label>
        <input type="text" id="newFileName" />
    </div>


    <button id="executeButton" onclick="executeOperation()">Execute</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showFields() {

           

            var operation = document.getElementById('operationCombo').value;
            var sourceField = document.getElementById('sourceField');
            var destinationField = document.getElementById('destinationField');
            var deleteField = document.getElementById('deleteField');
            var newFolderField = document.getElementById('newFolderField');
        var renameField = document.getElementById('renameField');
            var executeButton = document.getElementById('executeButton');


            sourceField.style.display = 'none';
            destinationField.style.display = 'none';
            deleteField.style.display = 'none';
            newFolderField.style.display = 'none';
            renameField.style.display = 'none';

           

            switch (operation) {
                case 'move':
                    sourceField.style.display = 'block';
                    destinationField.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
                case 'copy':
                    sourceField.style.display = 'block';
                    destinationField.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    deleteField.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
                case 'newfolder':
                    newFolderField.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
         case 'rename':
                    renameField.style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('sourcePathRename').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('destinationPathRename').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('newFileName').disabled = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

       function executeOperation() {
            var operation = document.getElementById('operationCombo').value;
            switch (operation) {
                case 'move':
                    var sourcePath = document.getElementById('sourcePath').value;
                    var destinationPath = document.getElementById('destinationPath').value;
                    moveFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath);
                    break;
                case 'copy':
                    var sourcePath = document.getElementById('sourcePath').value;
                    var destinationPath = document.getElementById('destinationPath').value;
                    copyFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath);
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    var deletePath = document.getElementById('deletePath').value;
                    deleteFilesWithWildcard(deletePath);
                    break;
                case 'newfolder':
                    var parentPath = document.getElementById('parentPath').value;
                    var newFolderName = document.getElementById('newFolderName').value;
                    createNewFolder(parentPath, newFolderName);
                    break;
         case 'rename':
                    var sourcePathRename = document.getElementById('sourcePathRename').value;
                    var destinationPathRename = document.getElementById('destinationPathRename').value;
                    var newFileName = document.getElementById('newFileName').value;
                    renameFile(sourcePathRename, destinationPathRename, newFileName);
                    break;
            }
        }

function renameFile(sourcePath, destinationPath, newFileName) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            if (fso.FileExists(sourcePath)) {
                try {
                    fso.MoveFile(sourcePath, fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, newFileName));
                    alert('Rename operation executed.\nSource: ' + sourcePath + '\nDestination: ' + destinationPath);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error renaming file: ' + e.message);
                }
            } else {
                alert('Source file not found.');
            }
        }

        function moveFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sourcePath);
            var wildcard = fso.GetFileName(sourcePath);
            var parentFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder);

            if (fso.FolderExists(parentFolder)) {
                try {
                    var files = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.Files);
                    var subFolders = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.SubFolders);
                    var regex = new RegExp(wildcard.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\*/g, ".*"), "i");

                    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                        var file = files.item();
                        if (regex.test(file.Name)) {
                            var sourceFile = fso.BuildPath(parentFolder, file.Name);
                            var destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name);
                            fso.MoveFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                        }
                    }

                    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                        var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                        if (regex.test(subFolder.Name)) {
                            var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                            fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                            moveFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error moving files/folders with wildcard.');
                }
            } else {
                alert('Parent path not found.');
            }
        }

        function moveFilesRecursive(folder, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);
            var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);

            for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                var file = files.item();
                var destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name);
                fso.MoveFile(file.Path, destinationFile);
            }

            for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                moveFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
            }
        }

        function copyFiles(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var folder = fso.GetFolder(sourcePath);

            if (fso.FolderExists(destinationPath)) {
                try {
                    copyFilesRecursive(folder, destinationPath);
                    alert('Copy operation executed.\nSource Path: ' + sourcePath + '\nDestination Path: ' + destinationPath);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error copying files/folders.');
                }
            } else {
                alert('Destination path not found.');
            }
        }

        function copyFilesRecursive(folder, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);
            var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);

            for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                var file = files.item();
                fso.CopyFile(file.Path, fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name), true);
            }

            for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                copyFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
            }
        }

 function moveFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sourcePath);
            var wildcard = fso.GetFileName(sourcePath);
            var parentFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder);

            if (fso.FolderExists(parentFolder)) {
                try {
                    var files = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.Files);
                    var subFolders = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.SubFolders);
                    var regex = new RegExp(wildcard.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\*/g, ".*"), "i");

                    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                        var file = files.item();
                        if (regex.test(file.Name)) {
                            var sourceFile = fso.BuildPath(parentFolder, file.Name);
                            var destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name);
                            fso.MoveFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                        }
                    }

                    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                        var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                        if (regex.test(subFolder.Name)) {
                            var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                            fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                            moveFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error moving files/folders with wildcard.');
                }
            } else {
                alert('Parent path not found.');
            }
        }

        function moveFilesRecursive(folder, destinationPath) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);
            var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);

            for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                var file = files.item();
                var destinationFile = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name);
                fso.MoveFile(file.Path, destinationFile);
            }

            for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                var newDestPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, subFolder.Name);
                fso.CreateFolder(newDestPath);
                moveFilesRecursive(subFolder, newDestPath);
            }
        }




    


    function copyFilesWithWildcard(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        if (fso.FileExists(sourcePath)) {
            // Source path is a single file
            var sourceFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sourcePath);
            var sourceFileName = fso.GetFileName(sourcePath);

            if (fso.FileExists(destinationPath)) {
                // Destination path includes a filename, create a new folder in the destination path
                var destinationParentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(destinationPath);
                var newFolderName = fso.GetBaseName(destinationPath);
                destinationPath = fso.BuildPath(destinationParentFolder, newFolderName);
            } else if (!fso.FolderExists(destinationPath)) {
                // Destination folder does not exist, create it
                fso.CreateFolder(destinationPath);
            }

            // Perform the copy operation
            fso.CopyFile(sourcePath, fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, sourceFileName));
            alert('Copy operation executed.\nSource: ' + sourcePath + '\nDestination: ' + destinationPath);
        } else if (fso.FolderExists(sourcePath)) {
            // Source path is a folder
            var parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sourcePath);
            var wildcard = fso.GetFileName(sourcePath);
            var parentFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder);

            if (fso.FolderExists(parentFolder)) {
                try {
                    var files = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.Files);
                    var subFolders = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.SubFolders);
                    var regex = new RegExp(wildcard.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\*/g, ".*"), "i");

                    // Collect files and folders matching the wildcard
                    var filesToCopy = [];
                    var foldersToCopy = [];

                    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                        var file = files.item();
                        if (regex.test(file.Name)) {
                            filesToCopy.push(file);
                        }
                    }

                    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                        var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                        if (regex.test(subFolder.Name)) {
                            foldersToCopy.push(subFolder);
                        }
                    }

                    // Perform the copy operation
                    if (!fso.FolderExists(destinationPath)) {
                        // Destination folder does not exist, create it
                        fso.CreateFolder(destinationPath);
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < filesToCopy.length; i++) {
                        var file = filesToCopy[i];
                        file.Copy(fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, file.Name));
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < foldersToCopy.length; i++) {
                        var folder = foldersToCopy[i];
                        copyFolderRecursive(folder, fso.BuildPath(destinationPath, folder.Name));
                    }

                    alert('Copy operation executed.\nSource: ' + sourcePath + '\nDestination: ' + destinationPath);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('Error copying files/folders with wildcard: ' + e.message);
                }
            } else {
                alert('Source parent path not found.');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Source path not found.');
        }
    }

  







  
    function copyFolderRecursive(sourceFolder, destinationFolder) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        fso.CreateFolder(destinationFolder);

        var files = new Enumerator(sourceFolder.Files);
        var subFolders = new Enumerator(sourceFolder.SubFolders);

        for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
            var file = files.item();
            file.Copy(fso.BuildPath(destinationFolder, file.Name));
        }

        for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
            var subFolder = subFolders.item();
            copyFolderRecursive(subFolder, fso.BuildPath(destinationFolder, subFolder.Name));
        }
    }

 

function createNewFolder(parentPath, newFolderName) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var fullPath = fso.BuildPath(parentPath, newFolderName);

            try {
                fso.CreateFolder(fullPath);
                alert('New folder created successfully.\nPath: ' + fullPath);
            } catch (e) {
                alert('Error creating new folder: ' + e.message);
            }
        }






    function deleteFilesWithWildcard(deletePath) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(deletePath);
        var wildcard = fso.GetFileName(deletePath);
        var parentFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder);

        if (fso.FolderExists(parentFolder)) {
            try {
                var files = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.Files);
                var subFolders = new Enumerator(parentFolderObj.SubFolders);
                var regex = new RegExp(wildcard.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\*/g, ".*"), "i");

                // Collect files and folders matching the wildcard
                var filesToDelete = [];
                var foldersToDelete = [];

                for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                    var file = files.item();
                    if (regex.test(file.Name)) {
                        filesToDelete.push(file);
                    }
                }

                for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
                    var subFolder = subFolders.item();
                    if (regex.test(subFolder.Name)) {
                        foldersToDelete.push(subFolder);
                    }
                }

                // Delete files
                for (var i = 0; i < filesToDelete.length; i++) {
                    filesToDelete[i].Delete();
                }

                // Delete folders
                for (var i = 0; i < foldersToDelete.length; i++) {
                    deleteFolderRecursive(foldersToDelete[i]);
                }

                alert('Delete operation executed.\nPath: ' + deletePath);
            } catch (e) {
                alert('Error deleting files/folders with wildcard: ' + e.message);
            }
        } else {
            alert('Parent path not found.');
        }
    }

    function deleteFolderRecursive(folder) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);

        for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
            var subFolder = subFolders.item();
            deleteFolderRecursive(subFolder);
        }

        fso.DeleteFolder(folder.Path);
    }




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).